# DLL not exporting string in visual studio 2013 VB code

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll, visual-studio-2013, interop

I'm writing a small application in VB.NET in Visual Studio 2013, and so far what I've written is the following code:

```vb
Public Class MainMenu

    Private Declare Function Version_Get Lib "mypath/mydll.dll" () As String   

    ' Before anyone asks, yes, the DLL is present in the mypath folder

    Private Sub MainMenu_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim Temp As String
        Dim Dummy As Integer

        On Error GoTo Handler
        Temp = Version_Get
        Dummy = 1 ' This line is never reached in debug mode

Handler:
        If Not IsNothing(Err.GetException()) Then
            MsgBox("Error " & Str(Err.Number) & " generated by the application " & Err.Source & ControlChars.CrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error")
            End
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Where the DLL is supposed to return a `BSTR` (this is of course `extern "C"` etc., but for the sake of comprehension I'm writing the function pure and simple):

File .h

```
#ifdef EVALFUNC_EXPORTS
#define EVALFUNC_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EVALFUNC_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C"
{
    EVALFUNC_API BSTR __stdcall Version_Get();
}
```

File .cpp

```
BSTR __stdcall Version_Get()
{
    CRegKey Key;
    CString sValue;
    BSTR Str;

    LONG nA = Key.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\my Software"), KEY_READ);

    // Before anyone asks, yes, the application is present in the system

    ULONG nValueLength = 0;
    LONG nB = Key.QueryStringValue(_T("Version"), NULL, &nValueLength);

    if (nValueLength > 0) LONG nC = Key.QueryStringValue(_T("Version"), sValue.GetBufferSetLength(nValueLength - 1), &nValueLength);    

    Str = sValue.AllocSysString();
    return Str;
}
```

The problem is that even if I wrote an error handler, the code encounters no error, and `Version_Get` makes my code crash without any error (the `MainMenu` form gets loaded anyway).

I tried the DLL on another VB environment (Excel) with the same declaration.

```vb
Private Declare Function Version_Get Lib "mypath/mydll.dll" () As String
```

In that case the string variable is filled with the correct text.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: VBA in Visual Studio 2013? Are you sure? Don't you meant VB.NET?

Comment: Sorry, I'm learning this stuff from scratch and by myself, and now that I think about it, VB.NET makes sense, while VBA doesn't

Comment: *Temp doesn't contain any string* or Version_Get returned an empty string (seems possible, there's not much error handling going on)? How do you know Version_Get is not executed? Did you run it under the debugger or under procmon or so?

Comment: I cannot execute procmon, because I don't have admin privileges, but in debug mode, the code stops at `Version_Get` and the next line is never reached. I know there is not much error handling, but the string *is supposed* to be returned (something like "4.1.2") because it works on other environments. There is no error in the DLL case.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are not using the built in classes in .Net for accessing the registry?  Why call out to a C++ dll?

Comment: Not a particular reason, but I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong here, since I have to use c++ dlls later as well. In this case it doesn't matter, but later on I will have performance problems, therefore the dlls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a class to import the Dll by marshalling the BSTR String:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class ImportDll

    <DllImport("myDll.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Public Shared Function Version_Get() As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)> String
    End Function
End Class
```

And could call the code as follows:

```
Version = ImportDll.Version_Get
```